# Product not adding in cart after add_filter() on woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

I have a scenario in which a non logged user can only add 1 product in his cart. I am adding a filter on `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` which works fine with `$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count>0` i.e. it displays a notice `You cannot add another product to your cart.0` however, if I do `$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count>1` the page just refresh without adding anything into cart. 
Below is my custom function for doing that.

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()):
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'woocommerce_add_cart_myfunction' );

function woocommerce_add_cart_myfunction( $cart_item_data ) {

    global $woocommerce;

$numberOfProducts=$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
    if($numberOfProducts > 1){
         wc_add_notice(
                     __( 'You cannot add another product to your cart.'.$numberOfProducts, 'woocommerce' ));
                return false;
    } 

}
endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the cart item data, if the number of products is only 1:

```
function woocommerce_add_cart_myfunction( $cart_item_data ) {

    $numberOfProducts = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;
    if ( $numberOfProducts > 1 ) {
         wc_add_notice(
                     __( 'You cannot add another product to your cart.'.$numberOfProducts, 'woocommerce' ));
         return false;
    }

    return $cart_item_data;

}
```

Comment: yes, I have done this with `$numberOfProducts < 2 && $numberOfProducts!=0` logic because `$numberOfProducts>1` was actually allowing to add `2` products in cart